# Electric shocks in every parts of house after Lightning

Tags: current, electricity

After yesterday's storms and lightning at our place, every thing in our house is giving electric shock. Floor, taps, gates and outside covers of electric plugs.

Comment: What is your question? If you seek advise: Leave that house immediately and do not enter it before an electrician has fixed the issue.

Comment: Please come back and leave a comment so we know you are not dead.

Comment: I am not dead, but even when main circuit breaker is switched off, there is shock everywhere, we are confused. Even government people working on same department couldn't fix it.

Comment: May I know, on which network of StackExchange, can we post these types of general questions, and not get [on hold]?

Answer (score 2):

*This question is off-topic but in order to avoid injury or death I offer the following.*

It sounds as though wiring overheated with high current caused by lightning. This has damaged the insulation at one or more points. It may also have burnt out your earth/ground wire and your metalwork is now live.

1. Use a phase tester to check for voltage at each point.
2. Switch off each circuit breaker or pull each fuse until the fault disappears to identify the source of the problem and remove the hazard.
3. Call electrician to check wiring and repair.